# MOSFET drain current parametrized to distance

Tags: mosfet, fet

In Id-Vgs Mosfet curves, sometimes, current is parametrized to a distance in micrometers. What is this parameter? Gate length, effective gate length, or width of the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

This length is the channel width. Since current is essentially proportional to channel width, giving a current relative to width is a good way to compare transistors.

This can also be done for other semiconductor devices. For example, you could report the current relative to the cross sectional area of a diode.